# A good way to extract a lower-case substring from a given position?

Tags: java, string

One I know is to apply a `Matcher` to a substring, another is just to perform a manual search for the first character not being lower-case.

So what are the good ways to do this?
Using a `Matcher` seems to be a huge overkill for such a simple task.

In fact it's possible using a method equivalent to C++ `find_first_not_of()`, but Java does not seem to have one in its library.

#### Update:

Well, the `Matcher` way of doing it is 4-10 times slower than doing it manually, though, if done properly, is nice and readable (see Andreas' answer).
However, being used to the thought the code should generally be as efficient as you can make it (keeping it readable), I am still interested to see if it's possible to do the same thing faster using the standard library and / or native Java tricks.

#### Update 2:

I found an idiomatic method which is a bit faster: stream API

So currently discovered methods are:

```
// 1. Andreas' correction of the Matcher way
static String getLowercaseSubstringAt (final String s, final int pos) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\p{Ll}+").matcher(s).region(pos, s.length());
    return (m.find() ? m.group() : "");
}
// 2. The same with a static Pattern: 2.5 times faster
//    I thought the compiler would optimize it by default
//    Don't like the idea to make the Pattern external
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\p{Ll}+");
static String getLowercaseSubstringAt (final String s, final int pos) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s).region(pos, s.length());
    return (m.find() ? m.group() : "");
}
// 3. Stream API with a range of indices: 3x the speed of the first
//    Makes use of the Java way to say `find_first(_not)_of()`
static String getLowercaseSubstringAt (final String s, final int pos) {
    int idx = IntStream.range(pos, s.length())
             .filter(i -> !Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(i)))
             .findFirst()
             .orElse(s.length());
    return s.substring(pos, idx);
}
// 4. Doing it manually. Relatively dirty, but fast. 10x the speed
static String getLowercaseSubstringAt (final String s, final int pos) {
    for (int i = pos; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (!Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(i)))
            return s.substring(pos, i);
    return s.substring(pos);
}
```

Stream API looks like the best choice in terms of language currently: no need for external resources, clean, relatively fast.

Comment: Why overkill? In the end, the regex engine parses the string and see if the next character matches the pattern, just like you'd do it yourself.

Comment: Be aware that the regex shown does not do the same as *"manual search for the first character not being lower-case"*. If the character at index 3 is not a lowercase, the manual search would stop immediately and you'd get an empty substring. With the regex, it will start by searching for the first lowercase, then search for the non-lowercase, and return that substring. E.g. if input had been `"!BLAHblahGH--n."`, manual search would see `'A'` at index 3 and stop immediately, but regex would find `"blah"` at index 5-8.

Comment: @f1sh, I'm not too deep into Java and cannot tell if the regex way is wasteful. Something tells me it is. Writing an improvised benchmark right now to check it

Comment: @Alex The regex does not find "a lower-case substring which starts **at** the given position." It finds a lower-case substring starting somewhere **at or after** the given position.

Comment: @Andreas, yes, now it's fixed

Comment: @f1sh, now you can see the test results of `Matcher` vs simpler methods. As I thought, the logic behind it is too complicated for this task

Comment: @Alex Regex is flexible and terse.  You can always beat its performance by writing a low-level equivalent, but you're typically dealing in microseconds of savings, even if your new version is many times faster.

Comment: @phatfingers, Regex is flexible, and I do not say it is generally bad - it is a really nice tool. But I'm against using large powerful tools for dumb tasks. In this case there might really be no point to run for such optimizations, but some low-level phylosophy inside me keeps saying that it's always good to learn to do things efficiently =)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you say the `Matcher` way is *really* wasteful, both in code and in time.

Sure, a regex is slower than a simple `for` loop, but unless you're doing this repeatedly in a tight loop (1000+ times), you will not notice the difference. Until you measure performance and see a problem, it's likely not a problem. Beware premature optimizations.

But wasteful in code? Only because you're doing it wrong:

```
static String getLowercaseSubstringAt (final String s, final int pos) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\p{Ll}+").matcher(s).region(pos, s.length());
    return (m.find() ? m.group() : "");
}
```

Since your non-regex was using full lowercase checking with `Character.isLowerCase()`, I've updated the regex to do that as well.

Comment: I'm aware of premature optimizations, but it's always good to know how to write good code in terms of speed and readability. "Only because you're doing it wrong" - your snippet is neat! Maybe, it's what I was looking for: the question was more about good language practices than winning a microsecond or two